# Prevent simultanous function calls when using pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, pdf, pdf.js

I use pdf.js to show pdf files, but the result is not good, please have a look at my code.

```
My codes are as follows.

var aaa = function (pdf, page_number) {
      pdf.getPage(page_number).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = $('.pdf-view')[page_number-1];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };  
        page.render(renderContext);
    }); 
};
for (var i = 1;i < 51;i++) {
    aaa(pdf, i);
    if (i !== 50) {
        var a = '<canvas data="{{ raw_path }}" class="pdf-view hide" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></canvas>';
        $('#file-view #pdf').append(a);
    } 
}
```

There is a loop, then 50 functions (`aaa`) execute at the same time. The effect is disastrous, and my computer gets stuck. I want to excute a function right after the last function excuted very well.

Please help me improve it. Thank a lot. (Sorry, my English is disastrous as well.)

Comment: Can you tell us what happens inside aaa() function. Is it an ajax function?

Comment: Hi, I added my codes, it is about canvas, not ajax. Have a look please

Comment: Pdf js uses promises and deferred objects to enable asynchronous processing. Use then() to attach functions to enable chaining. In current situation aaa() is called in a loop and it will simultaniously invoke aaa() 50 times.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @XPD, it looks like your comment helped the OP. You can make it an answer and make easier for others to find the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid simultaneous run of single page load and render function `aaa` , you should move its call to callback of the page load - `.then(` part so it's called recursively. And then call `aaa` function only once with `page_number = 1`.

```
//define page render function     
var aaa = function (pdf, page_number) {
          pdf.getPage(page_number).then(function(page) {
            var scale = 1.5;
            var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
            var canvas = $('.pdf-view')[page_number-1];
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            };  
            page.render(renderContext);

            if (i < 50) {
            //render first 50 pages but not all pages except #50
                aaa(pdf, i);
                i++;
            }

        }); 
    };

//pre-generate 50 canvases
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 1;i < 51;i++) {
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  $(c).data({{ raw_path }});
  $(c).addClass('pdf-view hide');
  $(c).css('margin-bottom', '10px');
  docfrag.appendChild(c);
}
 $('#file-view #pdf').append(docfrag);

    //call render
    var i = 1;
    aaa(pdf, i);
```

Comment: Great that it worked for you! If that's a solution - you can mark this answer as a correct