# Disable "close" button until modal view PDF is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using bootstraps modal view pop-up to display a PDF for my Terms of Use. I'm wondering if there is a way to disable the "close" button which is on the bottom of my modal view, until the user has scrolled to the bottom of the PDF. Currently the close button can be pressed anytime.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DisplayPDF</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <embed src="Terms of Use.pdf"
                               frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px">

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you use embed to display PDF you have no control over what's state of browsing the document. All the rendering is handled by the PDF plugin of browser.

Comment: I suggest you to try Bootstrap scrollspy https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/

Comment: Will look into this

Comment: This is nearly the exact same as a previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798543/detect-if-a-user-scrolls-to-the-bottom-of-an-embedded-pdf). You can't do this with the built-in PDF viewer, as its a separate plugin whose contents you cannot access. You'd need to use a separate PDF library to do this.

Comment: @Joseph any insight as to which plugin can do this? I see the question posted is also unanswered.

Comment: @Dada I believe PDF.js (the first answer in the post I linked talks about it) would work, but I haven't used it a ton in the past. It does render the PDF out as normal HTML elements, so you'd be able to keep track of the scroll position with a normal scroll event handler. Here's a link to their documentation on setup (you can install with NPM) - https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo

Comment: @Joseph got it working using that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've actually tried to recreate your issue using a simple div. Here is an example.
By default i've added the `disabled` attribute to the button and after scrolling to the bottom i've just removed that.

Here is the [js_bin_link](https://jsbin.com/rucutobeni/edit?output)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.accept-btn');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  if(wrapper.scrollTop === wrapper.scrollHeight - wrapper.offsetHeight) {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DisplayPDF</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    
                      <!-- <embed src="http://keiba-kinki.jp/pdf/0510_11.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px"></embed> -->
                      <div class="wrapper"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates odio saepe sed esse, illum tempore, voluptatibus, quisquam incidunt nemo deserunt quasi quos sunt in laborum officiis ipsum dolor, fugiat. Doloribus.</span>
                        <span>Laborum placeat soluta aliquam sit laboriosam dolorem quis a impedit quos voluptas deleniti rerum, commodi numquam in ducimus ut voluptate modi laudantium! Tempore molestiae a cumque at odit dolores libero.</span>
                        <span>Error incidunt earum, sint aspernatur quisquam. Saepe, similique, voluptatibus! Unde est commodi placeat deserunt, expedita nemo. Placeat rem ipsam, minima aliquid rerum voluptatem neque maxime sed? Corporis autem, pariatur officia!</span>
                        <span>Beatae suscipit eligendi pariatur a labore quas nostrum blanditiis maiores nesciunt, repudiandae quo excepturi fugiat qui provident nisi. Quia saepe nemo, sapiente. Tenetur ipsa voluptate error, velit itaque fuga harum.</span>
                        <span>Fuga, nulla, repellendus! Sed explicabo a, ipsa consequuntur incidunt iusto neque nisi! Quo soluta eius officia error suscipit distinctio fugiat quaerat, consequatur doloribus perferendis, deleniti, nostrum vel repudiandae fuga! Ea!</span>
                        <span>Soluta ab consequuntur culpa magnam doloribus tenetur iste at error debitis eius saepe veniam mollitia odit dignissimos veritatis id expedita accusantium qui reprehenderit fugit itaque commodi ea temporibus, accusamus! A!</span>
                        <span>Quas quam voluptate dolorem eos voluptas odio, inventore esse nobis, deleniti ipsam iusto quia reprehenderit repellat perspiciatis, natus animi tenetur non temporibus porro dolores quasi illo. Nesciunt ab, cum sapiente.</span>
                        <span>Animi, possimus consequuntur nihil eius voluptate ullam id corrupti, tempore aliquid ex aspernatur voluptatibus dolorem optio nobis laboriosam deserunt quas perferendis, sequi sunt assumenda cupiditate suscipit, architecto magni quae. Dignissimos.</span>
                        <span>Iure ducimus debitis et minus? Quae, aut! Esse quia doloribus aspernatur ex, debitis reprehenderit eaque asperiores, ratione quos explicabo ab tempore eligendi, optio error adipisci neque rem nihil. Amet, exercitationem!</span>
                        <span>Nesciunt aliquid cupiditate impedit, aspernatur assumenda rem nemo voluptatum tempora cum asperiores. Temporibus dignissimos aspernatur porro illum. Placeat dolore ratione nobis, veniam error asperiores eum a! Corporis a rem ad.</span>
                        <span>Nemo mollitia vitae quis, nesciunt similique iste aspernatur perspiciatis error ipsum facere eum impedit vel quod vero dolorem cumque officiis deserunt, sed provident repudiandae asperiores. Voluptate, aspernatur! Aliquam, ex facilis!</span>
                        <span>Earum, quos dolores possimus aspernatur sunt qui, corporis blanditiis voluptatibus, odio quasi perspiciatis architecto tempora odit iusto. Nam nihil, eaque aut autem vero tempore neque assumenda reprehenderit aliquid a ipsam!</span>
                        <span>Eius minus maiores, id reiciendis consectetur commodi, cum qui alias, ipsam laborum illum, asperiores nihil eum fuga voluptatum velit corporis. Doloribus at quae, vero corporis. At magni dignissimos incidunt id!</span>
                        <span>Iure saepe praesentium laudantium enim perferendis beatae, nesciunt, obcaecati, unde repudiandae aut tenetur et, eaque a. Aspernatur illum, repellendus labore temporibus qui quia explicabo beatae, cupiditate odio, architecto culpa placeat!</span>
                        <span>Nostrum quo eligendi ad voluptates veritatis perferendis. Illum maxime, nesciunt aliquid quidem, ipsum vero fugiat earum alias dolorum architecto tempore. Accusamus nisi esse dolores voluptatibus, ipsum, iste reiciendis ipsam eligendi.</span>
                        <span>Veritatis doloremque, exercitationem quae aspernatur id nemo sit quas. Consequuntur, quod. Provident repellat rem, quo doloribus, similique quis tempore iure quasi, voluptatibus perspiciatis sunt nobis, aspernatur soluta odit quibusdam. Laboriosam!</span>
                        <span>Rem dolorem enim porro fugit, dignissimos nulla magni, sint tempora nemo recusandae vel animi veritatis veniam aliquid culpa repellat aperiam, adipisci atque hic consequatur! Debitis voluptates, quia. Rerum, illo vitae.</span>
                        <span>Natus odit aliquid voluptates ullam, quia quod quisquam saepe assumenda molestias, est dicta culpa officiis doloremque libero nam reiciendis corporis qui laudantium illo suscipit unde asperiores. Corporis dolores in, dolorum!</span>
                        <span>Iure eligendi dolor porro. Dignissimos, delectus doloribus, ullam architecto id ab quos perspiciatis tenetur eos omnis aliquam mollitia quia iusto quae tempora beatae, placeat autem blanditiis, quisquam! Minus, saepe, aspernatur!</span>
                        <span>Blanditiis, voluptates delectus reprehenderit odio quibusdam ut obcaecati, officia fugit minima! Animi eos quae eius, vitae, voluptate illum commodi porro debitis! Corrupti nostrum eaque, odio. Quasi perspiciatis quibusdam similique? Tempore!</span>
                        <span>Laudantium eius repellendus, vel cupiditate a, fugit blanditiis deleniti maiores sunt, est explicabo dolor sed culpa nemo eligendi incidunt cum aliquam dicta. Aperiam sunt similique deleniti quibusdam aliquam veniam officiis!</span>
                        <span>Tempora perferendis quo labore quis vel porro eligendi, accusamus in pariatur ullam tempore ad magni sequi et. Fugiat, eum? Harum fugiat cupiditate cum nesciunt nemo saepe laborum ipsa perferendis voluptatum!</span>
                        <span>At excepturi laborum modi nisi voluptatum tenetur labore quam dolore illum magni. Autem commodi, fugiat maiores velit quasi odit est. Obcaecati possimus id cumque assumenda fuga repellat dolores quia cupiditate.</span>
                        <span>Dolor minus soluta deserunt eaque, reiciendis enim, assumenda fugit laborum deleniti sed tenetur qui adipisci hic consectetur aliquid possimus temporibus cumque nihil fugiat, dolorem! Animi, ex perspiciatis quae quo veritatis.</span>
                        <span>Eaque provident esse architecto quis. Corporis necessitatibus eveniet, a praesentium illo ex exercitationem dolores esse, aspernatur sint nemo unde, facere excepturi iure repellendus delectus est! Beatae aspernatur, quis enim repellendus.</span>
                        <span>Atque tempore vel, hic, impedit odit consequatur ea eveniet. Hic doloremque, sapiente magni, accusantium qui quibusdam sed nulla quas enim modi quisquam laboriosam, beatae rem aliquam esse delectus molestiae dignissimos.</span>
                        <span>Doloremque eius id, totam nesciunt. Laudantium molestiae quasi nihil numquam quaerat fugit rerum sequi incidunt iure quibusdam, magni voluptatibus ea, perferendis officia tenetur autem at? Nobis, nesciunt. Mollitia quo, porro.</span>
                        <span>Quos quis dignissimos dolorem nihil ipsum facilis porro nulla nostrum molestiae, mollitia doloremque deserunt sunt labore magni, ab modi qui eius vel nisi! Accusamus veniam, odio tenetur. Libero, eligendi, quod?</span>
                        <span>Minus perspiciatis iste, ipsa odio neque maiores incidunt ducimus, quis et fugiat, officiis enim alias ipsam vel doloribus soluta quam mollitia. Amet, impedit cum illum quidem, nihil dolorem ratione ea!</span>
                        <span>Minima unde debitis qui corrupti, neque atque accusantium id porro dignissimos eligendi. Est iusto sed minus quibusdam similique et fugiat, vitae tempore. Accusantium a asperiores quaerat veniam incidunt debitis, facilis?</span>
                        <span>Eius voluptate odit beatae, earum eos ipsa, laudantium esse minus hic rem dolores quasi harum, quibusdam sit error nam, ea facilis sunt cupiditate qui voluptatem quidem possimus pariatur deleniti? Quaerat.</span>
                        <span>Nihil quidem consectetur, illum praesentium molestias minima eligendi id ipsam voluptatum cumque? Numquam dolorem, praesentium odio velit accusantium at error non blanditiis quo, consequuntur, dolor dignissimos vel voluptas inventore iusto!</span>
                        <span>Nesciunt ipsam cum magnam alias est, nemo doloremque sunt sapiente et! Unde deserunt itaque consequuntur architecto, debitis autem rerum, inventore aspernatur ea, perspiciatis ad quas tempore soluta, quo aut laboriosam.</span>
                        <span>Quia quo officia, nobis veritatis laborum magni dolor libero minus, voluptatem ut! Dolorem, vel possimus adipisci tenetur inventore, minima tempora neque officiis reiciendis nihil reprehenderit ab deserunt ipsam temporibus ipsa.</span>
                        <span>Dolore labore inventore consequuntur reiciendis doloribus nostrum facere sunt maiores culpa quasi, odit dignissimos saepe incidunt provident! Totam dignissimos, dolorem animi aspernatur nesciunt commodi! Autem quis repudiandae ipsa amet asperiores.</span>
                        <span>Harum laborum quisquam unde enim commodi temporibus corrupti nam nisi odit labore reiciendis impedit eos dolores eveniet excepturi asperiores sunt vel praesentium delectus, deleniti maiores deserunt! Ut corrupti molestias aliquid.</span>
                        <span>Natus vitae, quis perspiciatis in eos voluptate vel tempore molestiae, veniam, voluptas, repellendus debitis assumenda? Esse illo distinctio nobis nihil inventore, doloremque fuga adipisci itaque veritatis, dolor veniam. Quibusdam, omnis!</span>
                        <span>Explicabo tempora ipsum dolorum necessitatibus quasi doloribus blanditiis fugit tenetur, debitis laudantium quas odio commodi molestiae autem consequatur velit culpa voluptas corporis cupiditate architecto deleniti esse saepe optio id. Eum.</span>
                        <span>Atque magnam similique, voluptate neque quod iusto. Nam delectus, illum esse repellendus nulla. Delectus consequuntur eius quas officia ipsam unde debitis alias tempore ullam accusamus fugiat, ea tempora ducimus amet.</span>
                        <span>Dicta voluptatum vero, eaque fugiat mollitia dolore deserunt doloremque commodi inventore, esse consequuntur earum dolores officia tempora aspernatur et, quisquam repudiandae sint explicabo perferendis? Maiores, voluptates, officia. Accusamus, deleniti, excepturi.</span>
                        <span>Assumenda ea, excepturi eum aliquid. Corrupti ullam illum nulla consequatur maxime nisi dolorum saepe veritatis accusamus, magni ab laborum nesciunt quis reiciendis a tempora. Quos accusantium cum excepturi, eaque mollitia?</span>
                        <span>Quaerat amet dolorum distinctio, architecto quis voluptatem enim quo laudantium ipsa suscipit at, quae porro laboriosam voluptates veritatis unde magni laborum reprehenderit, dolor, nobis perferendis cum! Deleniti possimus, voluptates nihil?</span>
                        <span>Rem, eveniet, cupiditate. Quisquam nesciunt soluta perspiciatis quaerat mollitia possimus iure voluptatibus accusantium hic officiis quasi aut ea, iusto neque architecto temporibus qui maiores ducimus aliquam blanditiis dignissimos minima odit.</span>
                        <span>Ducimus facere animi, voluptatem quo, iure modi natus harum maxime distinctio fugit consequuntur accusamus sequi ex eos enim praesentium, debitis accusantium deleniti tenetur quis, culpa laboriosam soluta dolorum! Est, libero.</span>
                        <span>Ad voluptas odit, accusantium quisquam earum mollitia, perspiciatis temporibus laborum aperiam consequatur autem sequi dolores id itaque vel laboriosam at, fuga similique sit eum nemo deleniti nulla. Ex, iste, aperiam!</span>
                        <span>Debitis obcaecati et iste, nesciunt laborum beatae consequatur explicabo libero voluptatem porro fuga quis, labore inventore nemo odio ipsa illum. Voluptatem provident velit nam delectus architecto nulla iste aliquam necessitatibus.</span>
                        <span>Beatae repellat, voluptatem recusandae. Earum ad placeat minima recusandae. Dicta autem rem, rerum, vitae atque placeat quibusdam expedita laboriosam asperiores quod unde ipsa voluptatum cum consectetur voluptas neque voluptates quae.</span>
                        <span>Vero neque sint, quibusdam ad assumenda. Dolorum eligendi explicabo placeat a esse earum unde pariatur exercitationem sit numquam soluta blanditiis quam, optio neque recusandae beatae dolorem, perferendis dignissimos tempora doloribus.</span>
                        <span>Enim sed, iure repellendus sequi esse placeat quo quae voluptas optio dolores maiores perferendis fugiat porro ipsam asperiores, odit possimus? Inventore voluptas amet, omnis quod sit explicabo corporis tempore, quos?</span>
                        <span>Amet reiciendis veniam sapiente ducimus minus odit magni culpa aspernatur numquam, fuga dolorum velit cum deleniti delectus impedit natus quidem cumque et. Expedita tempore et, unde impedit alias? Deleniti, nihil.</span>
                      </div>
                    
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default accept-btn" data-dismiss="modal" disabled>Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think he's asking about to enable or disable a button according to the scroll position. Not how to render the pdf. And to load pdf he just needs to add that embed tag inside the wrapper and use a valid pdf link that's all. This code will also work there.

Comment: @SifatHaque thanks, this is what I need. When I attach my PDF in embed, the close button stays un pressable, have you gotten it to work with a PDF?

Comment: Sorry i didn't tried pdf. I've actually shared the logic to enable or disable the button. But for pdf i think you need to keep in mind if the pdf content is loaded or not. Also the pdf height is dynamic so, i think you need to handle that differently. After that the logic is all the same to control the button's appearance.

Comment: This won't work with a PDF embed. You can't access the contents of an embedded PDF from JavaScript, as its using a separate plugin loaded by the browser. It acts similarly to a cross-domain iframe in that you can't access/change its contents.